# c# SQLite Insert Into Command with parameter

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am using c# to insert a record into the SQLite DB table 'VS_Types' with one parameter from table 'VS_Groups'. I test it with SQLite Browser and it works. While I implement the same sqlite command inside the C# with System.Data.SQlite. It doesn't work.

I modify the commandText to as following it works. Looks like the parameter '@value0' influence the c# SQLite command execution.

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO VS_Types(Name, Group_id, Color) Values('20', 10, 1245679);";
```

SQLite SQL:

```
SELECT @value0=ID FROM VS_Groups WHERE (Name = 'Ato_h');
INSERT INTO VS_Types(Name, Group_id, Color)  VALUES('20', @value0, 65536);
```

The Code inside the C#

```
using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(cs))
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(conn);
        cmd.CommandText = "Select @groudId = ID From VS_Groups Where(Name = 'Ato_h'); " 
        + "INSERT INTO VS_Types(Name, Group_id, Color) Values('20', @groudId, 1245679);";

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();

        testOutput.WriteLine("Insert Successful");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.testOutput.WriteLine("Failed to open connection: {0}", ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Please give me some suggestions about how to use the parameter inside C# Sqlite command in this situation.

Update: the VS_Groups and VS_Types table and its content

```
CREATE TABLE "VS_Groups" (
    `ID`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `Name`  TEXT,
    `Width` INTEGER,
    `Height`    INTEGER,
    `Flags` INTEGER,
    `Limi_recognition`  INTEGER,
    `Base`  TEXT,
    `Flags1`    INTEGER,
    `Limit_recognition` INTEGER,
    `Flags2`    INTEGER,
    `Limit_recognition2`    INTEGER,
    `Distance_threshold`    INTEGER
)

CREATE TABLE `VS_Types` (
   `ID` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
   `Name`   TEXT,
   `Group_id`   INTEGER,
   `Color`  INTEGER
)
```

The existing record is:9,Ato_h,160,140,65536,,,,400,,,100

Comment: Can you provide more detail about the exception thrown - such as its type, message, and any other data it contains as well as exactly which method invocation throws it?

Comment: There is no exception. Indeed the code execute to the "Insert successful" line. I will update the SQLite table content

Comment: Pretty sure `ExecuteNonQuery()` only works with a single statement (what's the point of that select anyways?). Plus you're not binding anything to `@groudId`...

Comment: I use the @groupId as a placeholder to store the result from Select query from VS_Groups and then insert this into table VS_Types

Comment: @Shawn  Recent versions of `System.Data.SQLite` command object will execute multiple statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqlite SQL does not work like that. You cannot declare and store a value in a variable, then reuse that variable later. **Terms like `@groudId` are only placeholders for parameters passed to the query.** That means that the expression `@groudId = ID` is NOT an assignment, rather it is a comparison. Since you are not binding the parameter `@groudId` to anything, the parameter value is null, so the expression is a comparison like `null = ID` which will result in false which numerically is 0 (zero). The select statement returns 0 and is not used in the INSERT statement.

If the INSERT is working at all, it is probably resulting in something like `INSERT INTO VS_Types(Name, Group_id, Color) Values('20', null, 1245679);`

At the end of the question, you also say "The existing record is ..." and you *only show a single record for VS_Groups*, although the insert statement is for the table VS_Types. **But you don't show output for the VS_Types table!  You are inspecting the wrong table for the inserted data.** If you query the table VS_Types, you will likely find many records with `Name == '20'`, `GroupID == null` and `Color == 123456789`... exactly as the INSERT statement says.

In summary, you are not using parameters correctly, but you really don't even need a parameter in the code you show, so it is difficult to know how to answer properly. An answer showing proper use of parameters would be wasted, but a replacement SQL may not be want you want in the end either. *I suggest researching parameters separately to learn how to use them properly.* For now, use this **nested** statement:

```
INSERT INTO VS_Types(Name, Group_id, Color) 
VALUES ('20', (Select ID From VS_Groups Where Name = 'Ato_h'), 1245679);
```

Regrettably that's not all.  The table definition does not show that `VS_Groups.Name` is unique, so technically there could be multiple rows that match the nested query, so the INSERT statement could still fail.  I suggest adding a UNIQUE constraint to the `VS_Groups.Name` column.

Comment: Hi Perkins, thanks for your answer. The nested statement is working. Indeed, VS_Groups.Name is unique. Thanks a lot. Your explanation about why “@groudId = ID" is very clear!